# search and get the tweets in a time range

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to write a java code to get the tweets within a special range of time.
I am using Since and Until functions in twitter4j api. However It only returns a limited number of tweets within last minutes.

is there a way to get it work? did any body have the same experience ?